# Nginx propagate server_name regex inside Php

Tags: nginx, server-name, http-host

In my Nginx configuration there’s

```
server_name ~^(?<domain>.*mygreatsite987778.com.invalid)$ ;
```

Which works quite good. But When Php does `echo $_SERVER['SERVER']`, it sees:

```
~^(?.*mygreatsite987778.com.invalid)$
```

Despite it seems logical, is there a way to get the server name that matched the regex? The server variable `HTTP_HOST` contains the good value (`stuff.mygreatsite987778.com.invalid`). I’d like to keep the `SERVER` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those variables are defined in your Nginx configuration file. You can set them to any value you require.

The variable you are looking at (which on my system is called `SERVER_NAME`) is using the value of the `$server_name` variable, but you would prefer to use the value of the `$host` or `$http_host` value.

Most of these variables are defined in a file called `fastcgi_params`, but you can override them individually by placing a statement after the include statement.

For example:

```
include       fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_param SERVER $http_host;
```

Comment: It's working. At least when I touch directly `fastcgi.conf`. When I configure the vhost, where everything else work as expected, it has no effect at all. Even removing the line in `fastcgi.conf` is of no use.

So, I would like to make it work by just modifying the vhost.